# /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed

Tags: 16.04, gnome, lvm

Boots very slowly, once booted, `boot.log` displays the following:

```
 lvmetad is not active yet, using direct activation during sysinit
  Volume group "ubuntu-vg" not found
  Cannot process volume group ubuntu-vg
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
  Reading all physical volumes.  This may take a while...
  Found volume group "ubuntu-vg" using metadata type lvm2
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
  2 logical volume(s) in volume group "ubuntu-vg" now active
```

How to solve this?

Additional info from `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /               ext4    noatime,errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=2728dcfe-e621-4e18-8266-fc4f0057148f /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0

tmpfs      /var/log        tmpfs      defaults,noatime        0    0
tmpfs      /tmp          tmpfs      defaults,noatime,mode=1777    0    0
```